# Looking for a headless driver for a C# Selenium test framework

Tags: selenium

Currently running test automation on Microsoft CRM using a C# .Net test framework supporting IE.  I would like to know if there exists a headless browser driver that I can replace the existing IE driver.

Answer (score 0):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is what you are looking for.